# table scroll is not working in IE

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am working with C#, MVC application.

In this application I have table with multiple columns and I need to add the horizontal scroll bar to the table in order to view all the results.

Following is my code that I have tried so far.

In Cshtml file,

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="totalResultList" class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width:2000px;">
       <thead>
         <tr>
         <tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <tr>
         <tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

In Css file,

```
.table-responsive 
{   
    width: 100%;
    /*width:2000px;*/
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-x: auto;   
    overflow-y: hidden;     
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    border: 1px solid #000000; 
}
```

This is working fine in Google chrome as shown in the below image.

[In chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHc92.png)

But In internet explorer nothing happens.

[In internet explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMuEn.png)

Comment: I am checking your code in chrome and IE. both are result different as per your image show.
IE Showing scroll bar when we hover on table.

Comment: @SunilBoricha, thanks for the reply.I didn't see any scroll bar when I hover on the table too.

Comment: Which IE you used for testing? I am testing IE 9 to edge. also check below link in IE is it working or not?
https://jsfiddle.net/nt9mrfhp/1/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, yes its working in that way. Maybe I have some issues in my table data. Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome dear, May be you fill table dynamically so facing issue.

Comment: Yes. Thats exactly the issue..:)

Answer (score 0):

Give table-layout:fixed to table and and apply width to 'table td' then you will get scroll in IE also